# Call Command from another class (WPF, Mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I made a Listbox with Checkboxes in it. The Listbox is bound to a List of my Checkbox class. Now i want to call a command from my DataContext instead of my Checkbox class when i check/uncheck the Checkbox

```
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5 5 0 0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

CheckBox class:

```
public class CheckBoxDatabase
{
    private string name;
    protected bool isChecked;
    public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxDatabase> Owner;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            setzeChecked(value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }

    }

    public virtual void setzeChecked(bool value)
    {
        isChecked = value;
    }


    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region NotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My main problem is if i add a command, it tells me that it is not found in the class (of course because i want it to call it in my datacontext class where i have a relaycommand. (also got another relay command independent of all this which is working where i did exactly the same)

Comment: why did you just remove the code for your checkbox class?

Comment: I thought it would not be relevant, i can add it again if needed

Comment: @PhilipK add it please

Comment: @Mitya i readded it, also added some more clarification. hope it helps :)

Comment: @PhilipK, I don't see any Command anythere in the code sample. Please edit the question and inlcude Command/DataContext definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind to an `ICommand` property of the class where the `Databases` source collection is defined, you could use a `RelativeSource`:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.YourCommandProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" Margin="5 5 0 0" />
```

Replace `YourCommandProperty` with the actual name of your property.

Comment: Thanks that did it!